# python selenium action chain

Tags: python, selenium

Need help here about "paste" action in web selenium in linux python3.
the copied content in local test.txt can successfully be paste into web context by using `search.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+ "v")`.

However, while I try to use actionchains to simulate the mouse "right click" and "paste", it failed. The script hang at "right click" board prompt out without doing anything like expected to [in the piucture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqE4i.png) "arrow down" and "paste" action.
seems I need to find the correct "element" to locate then execute "arrow down" and then "paste".
any idea are much appreciated.

```
def paste(self):
    file = 'test.txt'
    f = open(file,'r')
    c = clipboard.copy(f.read())
    sleep(3)
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='text'][@id='idtboxSensorSearch']")
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    actions.context_click().perform()
    actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()
```

Comment: Try to use `Keys.ENTER` instead of `Keys.RETURN` in this line ` actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).send_keys(Keys.RETURN).perform()` and let me know it is working or not?

Comment: Thank you Ali CSE, I tried and still not work, webdriver hang at "right click" board with nothing to do, I think the problem is driver failed locate the "element" of "right click" board, so all action still remain in web page "idtboxSensorSearch" box.

Answer (score 0):

The right-click menu is **an Operating System** UI element, it is beyond Selenium's control - it simply cannot interact with it. It's the same as if you try to control toolbar buttons or the browser menu - you can't do that with Selenium.
This is what happened with the ActionChains - it sends those events to the web element, not to the right click menu - and you see no interaction.

If you really want to do this - though ctrl-v is enough, it does the same, you should use a desktop applications automation tools. AutoIt, and Java's `robot` package come to mind as free options.